# How to publish message from AWS IoT to another host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

I would like to publish message from Amazon IoT to another host. In Amazon IoT there is MQTT client which have publish and subscribe functionalities. But as far as I know of MQTT client it can publish and subscribe with in Amazon only. I also checked aws iot commands. They don't provide commands for publish and subscribe. Can anyone suggest a way to publish messages from Amazon IoT to another host?

Comment: you found solution yet? same requirement here.